# PHP fopen fwrite = forbidden 403

Tags: php

I am trying to edit my index.php file via another php file. On my local test server (i use xampp) it runes great, but on my host it gives me 403 error I guess there is something wrong with my code.

This is the code i use

```
            <?php
            if($_POST){
            $open = fopen("../index.php","w+");
            $text = $_POST['update'];
            fwrite($open, $text);
            fclose($open);
            echo "File updated.<br />"; 
            }else{
            $file = file("../index.php");
            echo "<p>Welcome</p><br />"; 
            echo "<form action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\">";
            echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"150\" rows=\"40\">";
            foreach($file as $text) {
            echo $text;
            } 
            echo "</textarea>";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n
            </form>";
            }
            ?>
```

and save.php

```
            <?php

            $fs = fopen( $_POST["file"], "a+" ) or die("error when opening the file");

            fwrite($fs, $_POST["contents"]);

            fclose();

            ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps PHP runs with a different user at server side. You can check this by running `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`. Some users may have access where other don't.

Comment: I run whoami and i got my user "lubjor", but im not sure how that help me and where to use it in my code. Can you give me a hint?